# Svelte: Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, svelte

## Background

I am trying to use  [dgraph-js-http](https://github.com/dgraph-io/dgraph-js-http) in a Svelte application.

## Error

The initial error I was facing was:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: buffer is not defined
    <anonymous> http://localhost:5000/build/bundle.js:6947
```

I'm including this as maybe my solution to this was not the best, and that hopefully there is a way to solve both this issue, and the current blocker issue.

However, after a trial-and-error approach (see below for the various things I've tried) I'm now stuck.

### Current error

After solving the above error, I am now blocked on this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
```

## Attempts to resolve

None of the following have worked.

- Add `<script src="https://bundle.run/stream@0.0.2"></script>` to index.html
- Run `npm install stream`
- Add `import * as Stream from "stream"` to the App.svelte file
- Add `import * as Stream from "stream"` to the stores.js file
- Add `preferBuiltins:true` to `rollup.config.js`
- Add `npm install --save-dev rollup-plugin-node-polyfills`
- Add `preferBuiltins:false` to `rollup.config.js`. This resolved prior errors and resulted in the new error of: `Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined`
- Add `npm install --save define`. This, now results in the current blocker:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
```

Comment: Same. Any updates on this?

Comment: Nope, gave up on Svelte for now.

Comment: It seems you are using rollup and It's likely a rollup issue. Did you try adding `@rollup/plugin-node-resolve` plugin in your `rollup.config.js``?

Comment: No - I don't think I tried that one.

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed `type: "module"` attribute in package.json. Here, the type attribute represents whether the type of javascript interpreter is commonjs or   babel. `type: "module"` indicates that you are going to use babel as the ECMA script interpreter.